# Autocomplete: Как выводить определенное кол-во элементов для одной категории?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Помогите выводить нужное кол-во элементов в категории. Например 3 для каждой категории.
Я пробую итерировать items в **_renderMenu**, item в **_renderItemData** и в результатах аякс запроса. Все в бестолку.

Использую этот [плагин](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories).

в `data` у меня массив из хешей:

```
data = [{ label: "item", category: "category" }, { label: "item", category: "category" }]
```

Вот код

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
  _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li style='clear:both'class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            self._renderItemData(ul, item);
        });
    }
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( 'input[name="query"]' ).catcomplete({
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 4,
    source: function(request, response){
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/autocomplete.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{ query: request.term },
        success: function(data){
          if (data.length > 0) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
              return {
                label: item.label,
                id: item.id,
                category: item.category,
                value: item.value
              }
            }));
          }else{
            response([{ category: 'No results found', label:""}]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: у вас обращение то к файлу, или `autocomplete.json` этот генерируется?

Comment: `autocomplete.json` это эндпоинт

Comment: а на русском это что значит? статика или генерится. если последнее, формировать с ограничениями надо на стороне сервера. Если это не возможно, то опишите это в задаче.

Comment: и где в примере данных поля `id`, `value`, которые фигурируют в коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот модифицированный пример, на который вы ссылаетесь.

когда получите данные `data`, просто отфильтруйте записи подсчитывая число элементов в категории:

```
var ccount = {} ;
var itemsPerCategory = 2;
data = data.filter(function(item){
               if(! ( item.category in ccount)){
                    ccount[item.category] = 0;
               }
               return ccount[item.category]++  < itemsPerCategory;
         }));
```

а дальше уже делайте, что хотели.

```js
  $( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
      },
      _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
          currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
          var li;
          if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
            currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
          if ( item.category ) {
            li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
          }
        });
      }
    });
    var data = [
      { label: "anders", category: "" },
      { label: "andreas", category: "" },
      { label: "antal", category: "" },
      { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
      { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
    ];
 
    var itemsPerCategory = 2;
 
    $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
      delay: 0,
      source:  function(request, response){
                  var ccount = {} ;
                  response(data.filter(function(item){
                       if(! ( item.category in ccount)){
                           ccount[item.category] = 0;
                       }
                       return ccount[item.category]++  < itemsPerCategory;
                     }));      
             }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


<input id="search">
```